# Load View in View CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to load a `view` which come from logical statement (in `controller`) IN a `view`. Simply like this

**Controller**

```
 public function index(){
   $this->lib();
   $this->view('main');
 }
 public function lib(){
   if(TRUE){
     // $this->view('something1') in $this->view('main')
   }
   else{
     // $this->view('something2') in $this->view('main')
   }
 }
```

** View **

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- view from $this->view('main') -->
<!-- want to show view from lib() -->
</body>
</html>
```

How to show `$this->view('something')` get from `lib()` in `$this->view('main')` ? Any idea ?

Comment: what the issue ?

Comment: what is `TRUE` is condition?

Comment: try `return $this->view('main',[],true);`

Comment: @Tiara your question is not clear, can you tell us what exactly do you want?

Comment: I've edited the question. I want to show `view` inside the `view`

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I've found works is this:

Controller:

```
public function index() {

     $data['internal_view'] = $this->load->view('stmt', [], true);
     $this->load->view('main', $data);

}
```

"main" View:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo $internal_view; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: the 3rd param in `view` allows for the view to be returned as a string rather than automatically outputted to the browser. Because of this functionality, you can assign a view as a return string from another function and use it to generate `internal_view` or whatever you decide to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You could preserve the **main** view and also keep the **lib** conditional view and pass it to the main controller.
Controller :

```
public function index(){
    $data['lib_view'] = $this->lib();
    $this->view('main', $data);
}

public function lib(){
    if(TRUE){
        return $this->load->view('something1', true);
    }
    else{
        return $this->load->view('something2', true);
    }
}
```

'main' View :

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- view from $this->view('main') -->
<?php echo $lib_view ?>
</body>
</html>
```